# JavaScript Count matches on filtered variable

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app where you can filter trough all business partners. I've managed to accomplish this. Now i'm trying to show the count the amount of matches.

Looking into this it I think I cant filter an already filtered variable is this correct?

> How can I display the matches in an filtered variable?

I've tried to filter the filtered result and count the true boolean

```
    results = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;
    result = document.getElementById("result");

    var count = results.filter(function(s) { return s.value; }).length;
    console.log("#True: " + count)

    result.innerHTML = results.length;
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, results, result;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Adele</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>james</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>frank</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>rupert</h3></a>
  </li>
  
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Bert</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Jordan</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Peele</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Gunter</h3></a>
  </li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
  <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Adele</h3><br>
  <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Lubert</h3><br>
  <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Agny</h3><br>
  <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Loki</h3></a></li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Thor</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Robert</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>frank</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Chris</h3></a>
  </li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Sean</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Shawn</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Shuan</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>rupert</h3></a>
  </li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Johhny</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Urkel</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Uruk</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Derk</h3></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code snippet is not working

Comment: @Nirali I've edited the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just declaring a number like `filterCount` and incrementing it each time you filter a result?

See the snippet below.

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, results, result, matches = 0;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            matches++;
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {            
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    // displaying the number of filtered results
    document.getElementById("matchesCount").innerHTML = matches;
    
    // showing the label in case at least one result is filtered
    if (matches < li.length) {
      document.getElementById("showNumberMatches").style.display = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("showNumberMatches").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2> <span id="showNumberMatches" style="display:none"><span id="matchesCount"></span> results match your query</span>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Adele</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>james</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>frank</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>rupert</h3></a>
  </li>
  
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Bert</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Jordan</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Peele</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Gunter</h3></a>
  </li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
  <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Adele</h3><br>
  <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Lubert</h3><br>
  <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Agny</h3><br>
  <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Loki</h3></a></li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Thor</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Robert</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>frank</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Chris</h3></a>
  </li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Sean</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Shawn</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Shuan</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>rupert</h3></a>
  </li>

    
  <li><a href="#">
    <b>Contact Name:</b><h3>Johhny</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Company:</b><h3>Urkel</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Phone:</b><h3>Uruk</h3><br>
    <b>Contact Business:</b><h3>Derk</h3></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is amazing, only concern is that it counts the li's that don't match instead of counting the once that do.

Comment: @Salman i edited the snippet so that it shows the number of matches instead.